# User comments in TYPO3

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3

I have to learn TYPO3 4.3 for my new job (I don't have much time). I already grasped some back-end stuff and basics of typoscript, but since I learn best by doing, my first goal is to build a blog based on that CMS. I don't want to use any existing blog extensions, because I want to learn to write them myself. I want to be able to tag pages (my blog entries) and enable users to put comments under the blog entry - the usual wordpess stuff.

Could anyone give me some tips and point me to places with some useful resources, so I can reach my goal?

Comment: Look into the code of existing extensions that does so and learn from that code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try the new extension framework "extBase". There's a [book](http://www.amazon.de/Zukunftssichere-TYPO3-Extensions-mit-Extbase-Fluid/dp/3897219654) which walks you through the creation of a blog example extension.

Unfortunatly the book is only available in German, but there's an effort under way to [translate it to English](http://news.typo3.org/news/article/extbasefluid-book-in-english/). With a little help from Google you might be able to find an English version (translation in progress) of the book online...

The blog example extension is also available in the public extension repository: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/blog_example/current/ or http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3-mvcblogexample

Comment: @maholtz extBase 1.1 is included in the 4.3 package

Answer (score 0):

You can find some good developer tutorials at typo3 wiki: http://wiki.typo3.org/Overview_Developer_Manuals. There is also some documentation about extBase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the news extension (tt_news) plus the comments extension together to form a basic blog within minutes (well maybe an hour or so with some styling), no coding required.

We have an editors guide available at http://www.seethroughweb.com/typo3-support.html, which doesn't go into development at all, but is helpful for getting a handle on how editors can work with a site.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

As TYPO3 is an open source project, and all extensions are open source too, the best way, it's to analyze them, and to hack.

So, You should install some extensions, which are near on functional level to Your future blog extension and simple enough, and to hack it in different way, using version control to have the possibility to backup Your experiments.

Extensions, which I could advice You : **comments, tt_news**.

Probably You will need some time in the begining to install and configure these extensions.

Answer (score -2):

Use existing extensions. That's the best advise. Because those were tested by many users.
But if you want to write an own version, buy some books (for old or new way) and take an existing version as example.

Comment: I have to know how to write extensions, because that's going to be my job.